# how to use threading in c++ which points to another class

Tags: c++, boost-thread

i need to use the function in another class file as thread

```
int main()
{
master t;

boost::thread t1(boost::bind(t.start, "exampl"));

t1.join();
}
```

i have an class `master` and a function `start` ..i need to pass an value to it and run 
i have used this in same class it works fine...can any one tell me where i am wrong

Answer (score 7):

You need to bind the member function to the instance:

```
boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&master::start, t, "exampl"));
```

Comment: The OP might want to write `boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&master::start, &t, "exampl"));` (passing `&t` instead of `t` to `bind`) if copying the `master` object is undesirable or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

James's solution will have your master object copied. If you want to sort of pass by reference, then

`boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&master::start, &t, "exampl"));`

HTH